# How do I read console input / stdin in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io

How do I read console input from `stdin` in Dart?

Is there a `scanf` in Dart?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The *readLineSync()* method of *stdin* allows to capture a String from the console:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('1 + 1 = ...');
  var line = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8);
  print(line?.trim() == '2' ? 'Yup!' : 'Nope :(');
}
```

Old version:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
    print('1 + 1 = ...');
    var line = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'));
    print(line.trim() == '2' ? 'Yup!' : 'Nope :(');
}
```

Comment: This reads to the first new line, how do I read the entire stdin? Can I just do `stdin.toString` or something?

Answer (score 22):

The following should be the most up to date dart code to read input from stdin.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  readLine().listen(processLine);
}

Stream<String> readLine() => stdin
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(const LineSplitter());

void processLine(String line) {
  print(line);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
  stdout.write("Enter your name : ");
  var name = stdin.readLineSync();
  stdout.write(name);
}
```

Output

```
Enter your name : Jay
Jay
```

By default readLineSync() takes input as string. But If you want integer input then you have to use parse() or tryparse().

Comment: Why don't you just use `print` instead of `stdout`?

Comment: Yes, we can use print. I'm just getting used with stdout that's why I use it.

Comment: "stdout provides more functionality than the print() function. For example, you can display the contents of a stream with stdout. However, you must use print() instead of stdout for programs that are converted to and run in JavaScript." Read: https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/cmdline

Comment: One more reason to use `stdout.write()`, 
With print(), it adds a "newline" character at the end of the statement. but in case of `stdout.write()`, it only prints whatever input is passed and the next stdout.write continues from the same position instead of starting from a new line.

Answer (score 4):

With M3 dart classes like StringInputStream  are replaced with [Stream](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/Stream.html), try this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  print("Please, enter a line \n");
  Stream cmdLine = stdin
      .transform(new StringDecoder())
      .transform(new LineTransformer());

  StreamSubscription cmdSubscription = cmdLine.listen(
    (line) => print('Entered line: $line '),
    onDone: () => print(' finished'),
    onError: (e) => /* Error on input. */);


}
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Dart 2.12, null-safety is enabled, and `stdin.readLineSync()` now returns a `String?` instead of a `String`.

This apparently has been confusing a lot of people.  I highly recommend reading https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety to understand what null-safety means.

For `stdin.readLineSync()` specifically, you can resolve this by checking for `null` first, which for *local* variables will automatically promote a `String?` to a `String`.  Here are some examples:

```dart
// Read a line and try to parse it as an integer.
String? line = stdin.readLineSync();
if (line != null) {
  int? num = int.tryParse(line); // No more error about `String?`.
  if (num != null) {
    // Do something with `num`...
  }
}
```

```dart
// Read lines from `stdin` until EOF is reached, storing them in a `List<String>`.
var lines = <String>[];
while (true) {
  var line = stdin.readLineSync();
  if (line == null) {
    break;
  }
  lines.add(line); // No more error about `String?`.
}
```

```dart
// Read a line.  If EOF is reached, treat it as an empty string.
String line = stdin.readLineSync() ?? '';
```

Note that you should **not** blindly do `stdin.readLineSync()!`. `readLineSync` returns a `String?` for a reason: it returns `null` when there is no more input.  Using the [null assertion operator](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator) (`!`) is asking for a runtime exception.

Answer (score 3):

Note that while calling `stdin.readLineSync()` your `isolate/thread` will be blocked, no other `Future` will be completed.

If you want to read a `stdin` `String` line asynchronously, avoiding `isolate/thread` block, this is the way:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

/// [stdin] as a broadcast [Stream] of lines.
Stream<String> _stdinLineStreamBroadcaster = stdin
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(const LineSplitter()).asBroadcastStream() ;

/// Reads a single line from [stdin] asynchronously.
Future<String> _readStdinLine() async {
  var lineCompleter = Completer<String>();

  var listener = _stdinLineStreamBroadcaster.listen((line) {
    if (!lineCompleter.isCompleted) {
      lineCompleter.complete(line);
    }
  });

  return lineCompleter.future.then((line) {
    listener.cancel();
    return line ;
  });
}
```

Comment: This is actually helpful. My background isolate was completely blocked with readLineSync.

Answer (score 2):

All these async API readLine*() based solutions miss the syntactic sugar which gives you the ability to do everything without synchronous blocking, but written like synchronous code. This is even more intuitive coming from other languages where you write code to execute synchronously:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  var lines = stdin.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(const LineSplitter());
  
  await for (final l in lines) {
    print(l);
  }
  print("done");
}
```

The key takeaway here is to make use of `async` and `await`:

- `async` on your method is required, as you're using `await` to interface with asynchronous API calls
- `await for` is the syntax for doing "synchronous-like" code on a `Stream` (the corresponding syntax for a `Future` is just `await`).

Think of `await` like "unwrapping" a `Stream`/`Future` for you by making the following code execute once something is available to be handled. Now you're no longer blocking your main thread (`Isolate`) to do the work.

For more information, see the [Dart codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) on async/await.

(Sidenote: The correct way to declare any return value for an `async` function is to wrap it in a `Future`, hence `Future<void>` here.)

Answer (score 2):

To read from the console or terminal in Dart, you need to:

1. import 'dart:io' library
2. store the entered value using stdin.readLineSync()!
3. parse the input into an int using int.parse(input) if necessary

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  String? string;
  var number;

  stdout.writeln("Enter a String: ");

  string = stdin.readLineSync()!;

  stdout.writeln("Enter a number: ");

  number = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line to read a **string** from the user:

```
String str = stdin.readLineSync();
```

OR the following line to read a **number**

```
int n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

Consider the following example:

```
import 'dart:io'; // we need this to use stdin
void main()
{
    // reading the user name
    print("Enter your name, please: ");
    String name = stdin.readLineSync();
  
    // reading the user age
    print("Enter your age, please: ");
    int age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  
    // Printing the data
    print("Hello, $name!, Your age is: $age");
  
  /* OR print in this way
   * stdout.write("Hello, $name!, Your age is: $age");
   * */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could of course just use the dcli package and it's ask function

```dart
Import 'package: dcli/dcli.dart':
Var answer = ask('enter your name');
print (name);
```

Use the named validator argument to restrict input to integers.