# What is equivalent of Cin in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I first learned C++ in school. Now i started learning dart online. Like in C++ we use Cout to print out our result and its equivalent in Dart is Print(). what is the equivalent of Cin in Dart like how we input data from user in Dart coding?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122732/how-do-i-read-console-input-stdin-in-dart), dart.io library has stdin object that you can use

Comment: Hi, does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you are using dart, `stdin.readLineSync` would help.

Secondly, if you are going to use Flutter, you can use a `TextField` to allow user input strings. You can also use other kinds of UI elements, such as `FlatButton`s.